# Cython class executing a list of cython classes of the same kind

Tags: python, cython

I have defined a generic class `Rule` in Cython which expects a `cdef` method  ̀`initialize`. I have created a class which is itself defined as a `Rule`, but it executes the `initialize` methods of a list of rules:

```py
%%cython

cdef class Rule:
    cdef initialize(self, const int i):
        pass


cdef class Print(Rule):
    cdef int number
    
    def __init__(self, int number):
        self.number = number
    
    cdef initialize(self, const int i):
        print(self.number, i)


cdef class ChainRule(Rule):
    cdef list rules
    cdef int number_of_rules, j
    
    def __init__(self, rules):
        self.rules = rules
        self.number_of_rules = len(rules)
    
    cdef initialize(self, const int i):
        for j in range(self.number_of_rules):
            self.rules[j].initialize(i)


def run(Rule rule, const int i):
    rule.initialize(i)
```

The following code works when ̀run` takes Print as input:

```py
rule1 = Print(1)
rule2 = Print(2)

run(rule1, 100)
```

But the ChainRule class which calls the rules internally does not work:

```py
chain_rule = ChainRule([rule1, rule2])
run(chain_rule, 100)
```

Error message:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_12612/3538048733.py in <module>
      4 chain_rule = ChainRule([rule1, rule2])
      5 
----> 6 run(chain_rule, 100)

_cython_magic_d892e8623ea7126dd1dda2c25ea23c19.pyx in _cython_magic_d892e8623ea7126dd1dda2c25ea23c19.run()

_cython_magic_d892e8623ea7126dd1dda2c25ea23c19.pyx in _cython_magic_d892e8623ea7126dd1dda2c25ea23c19.ChainRule.initialize()

AttributeError: '_cython_magic_d892e8623ea7126dd1dda2c25ea23c19.Pri' object has no attribute 'initialize'
```

Why does it fail? How can I make it work?

Thank you.

Edit, a working solution:

```py
cdef class ChainRule(Rule):
    cdef list rules
    cdef int number_of_rules, j
    
    def __init__(self, rules):
        self.rules = rules
        self.number_of_rules = len(rules)
    
    cdef initialize(self, const int i):
        cdef Rule rule
        for j in range(self.number_of_rules):
            rule = self.rules[j]
            rule.initialize(i)
```

Comment: `self.rules[j]` is of type object (as far as Cython is concerned) and thus a def-function `initialize` is called (see generated C-code to confirm that), which doesn't  exist. If you don't type `self.rules[i]` you cannot access cdef-functions.

Comment: Interesting. Ya, try using `cpdef` for your method `ChainRule.initialize()`, see if cython has access to this method.

Comment: Thanks ead, you are right if I add "cdef Rule rule" in the beginning of ChainRule.initialize then it works.