# How do I pass a C object when using Cython? (I get the error: Cannot convert Python object to class_name)

Tags: python, cython

I have a minimal example below. The cpp classes are in uppercase, and cython classes in lowercase. This statement: `self.ip = new BCD(ob.ip[0].obj_abc)` gives me an error which says: `Cannot convert Python object to 'ABC'` though `ip` is a pointer to `class BCD` which holds `obj_abc`. How do I access `obj_abc` embedded in `BCD` through the pointer?
(the first three definitions are in `.pxd` file, and the last in `.pyx` file)

```
cdef cppclass ABC:
    ABC()
    
cdef cppclass BCD:
    ABC obj_abc
    BCD(ABC &)
    BCD()

cdef class bcd:
    cdef BCD * ip
            
cdef class bcd:
    def __cint__(self, ob=None):
        if ob is not None:
            self.ip = new BCD(ob.ip[0].obj_abc)
            # isinstance(ob, bcd) is True
        else:
            self.ip = new BCD()
```

EDIT: based on @ead's answer. Changing the `def` line to
`def __cint__(self, bcd ob=None):` works.

Comment: This the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/q/68540429/5769463, even in a different context: cython doesn't know that `ob` is of type `bcd` and thus cannot access cdef-members.

Comment: thank you. when I add `isinstance(ob, bcd)` it does print True, so I am assuming Python knows that `ob` is of type `bcd` but what you mean is Cython does not know about it? Is there a work around for this? (I tried what was suggested in the answer pointed by the link, i.e. have `cdef ABC x` and assign x to `ob.ip[0].obj_abc`, but I get the same error)

Comment: Python can determine during the run time the type of `ob` (it depends on what you put into the function), cython doesn't know it at compile time.

Comment: the problem is the unknown type of `ob` (you should type it) and not the type of `ob.ip[0].obj_abc`.

Comment: thanks. yes, having the line `def __cint__(self, bcd ob=None):` (adding `bcd`) works. I was trying to pass a list of characters or an object of `class bcd` depending on the context, and had different pieces of code depending on whether a list was passed or `bcd` object was passed. Now I guess I need to add one more argument, and separate out the two.